# flutter failed to connect android device and off application on iPhone simulator

Tags: flutter

when I call debug mode on an android device

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:60027/bncnE_T-mWw=/
```

and also asks for permission to wifi, but through a notification, if I give permission, it shows a white screen and the same error

but everything starts quietly if you build the apk and install through it

with an iPhone simulator, the application starts and immediately closes, and in the android studio it is written that the connection is taking too long, it may have crashed

flutter doctor:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 2.5.0 at /Users/daniil/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4cc385b4b8 (6 days ago), 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
    • Engine revision f0826da7ef
    • Dart version 2.14.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/daniil/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi Note 8T (mobile) • 19645373                             • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • iPhone 8 Plus (mobile) • 06EE905E-8A76-45D5-A844-8DCDF2EEA3CA • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android the problem was solved by delete update "security" on firmware MIUI